# Get specific el. class if it has many classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get zoneID-37 by checking if it has class 'drag-circle'? I can select the element by

```
$('.drag-circle')
```

but then what?

```
 <div class="circle circleID-0 zoneID-37 drag-circle" style="top: 201px; left: 382.5px;"></div>
```

Comment: you want it as a plain string..? we can get it by converting them as an array of string, but it wont be reliable since the order of classes may gets change..

Comment: And does it always start with `zoneID`, and do you really just need the number ?

Comment: Yes, I want it as plain string. Number And it always starts with zoneID

Answer (score 4):

```
var classes = $('.drag-circle').get(0).className;

var numb = classes.match(/zoneID-(\d+)/);

var klass  = numb ? numb[0] : null; // zoneID-37
var number = numb ? numb[1] : null; // 37
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Js5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all classes using attr() funciton

```
$('.drag-circle').each(function(){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    //Your code here to check a class in array of classes

})
```

Yet I'd rather suggest you storing the values in data attribute. Ex.
HTML

```
<div class="circle circleID-0 zoneID-37 drag-circle" data-zoneID="37"  style="top: 201px; left: 382.5px;"></div>
```

and access it by

```
$('.drag-circle[data-zoneID]')
```

or specific zone by

```
$('.drag-circle[data-zoneID="37"]')
```

Comment: @Esa Yeah.. I forgot to put 'data-' my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use an attribute selector checking if the class "contains" (using '~=') your value:

```
if ($('.drag-circle[class~="zoneID-37"]')) {
    // Your code here
}
```

EDIT: Added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JLXu/1/) to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

you can get list of all classes then check it have that class or not.
jquery

```
   var classList =$('div').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
if(item === 'drag-circle')
{
    alert(classList[2]);
}
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/WLCTt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

OMG this question is easily solved by css no need for lines of codes in js

```
$(".drag-circle.zoneID-37")
```